# Can I use this cheap GPS module with arduino

Tags: arduino-uno, gps

For my project I need a GPS module, it should be cheap and I should be able to use it with arduino, after some search I got a product on ebay, I'm a 16 year old school boy and I didn't know that it will work with Arduino or not. Help me.

Here is the link--
http://www.ebay.co.uk/itm/DIYMALL-VK16E-Module-Gmouse-GPS-Module-SIRF3-Chip-with-Ceramic-Antenna-TTL-Level-/181594912168?hash=item2a47e675a8

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some research it seems you can use that gps module with an Arduino. Here's a link to the data sheet for it: http://www.hanssummers.com/images/stories/ultimategps/vk16e.pdf. Also it seems like you have to use the TinyGPSPlus library to get it to work. Here's a link to learn more about it: http://arduiniana.org/libraries/tinygpsplus/. You may have to use the protocols in this data sheet: https://www.sparkfun.com/datasheets/GPS/NMEA%20Reference%20Manual-Rev2.1-Dec07.pdf.

All of this information was taken from this thread: https://www.linkedin.com/grp/post/4573843-5806249757395406852.

Answer (score 1):

Yes.  You can tell that from two entries in the specification:

> TTL Level 9600 Baud Rate

That tells you it uses standard TTL (5V) serial to communicate, so on an Uno that would be pins 0 and 1 and the Serial object, or any pins of your choice and the SoftwareSerial library.

> Output SiRF binary system OR **nmea0183 V3.0**(GGA, GSA, GSV, RMC, VTG)

It outputs NMEA encoded data (bold added by me) which is what most of the Arduino GPS libraries are written to use.